Error: Cannot find module opus.node - trying the wrong directory?
I'm trying to get an old project working again and after cloning it with no changes from what used to work I've been getting a cannot find module error.
Here is the full error:
Error: Cannot find module '/home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/prebuild/node-v127-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.39/opus.node'
Require stack:
- /home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/lib/index.js
- /home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/discord-speech-recognition/dist/bot/events/speech.js
- /home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/discord-speech-recognition/dist/bot/events/index.js
- /home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/discord-speech-recognition/dist/bot/addSpeechEvent.js
- /home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/discord-speech-recognition/dist/index.js
- /home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1038:27)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:212:19)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1297:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:123:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/lib/index.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1460:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1544:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/@discordjs/opus/lib/index.js',
    '/home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/discord-speech-recognition/dist/bot/events/speech.js',
    '/home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/discord-speech-recognition/dist/bot/events/index.js',
    '/home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/discord-speech-recognition/dist/bot/addSpeechEvent.js',
    '/home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/node_modules/discord-speech-recognition/dist/index.js',
    '/home/kyle/projects/Chill-Bot-2.0/index.js'
  ]
}

Tried pretty much every solution I can find online--deleting package.json and package-lock.json, reinstalling every package, etc.
pretty sure the issue is that the node-v127-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-2.39 folder its trying to go to is actually called node-v93-napi-v3-linux-x64-glibc-unknown-unknown but I've got no clue how to change that
thanks in advance!

The project is deprecated, you'll need to work through updating it to fit any new changes from discord.js
